# HTML/CSS Image Rollover/Animation, specific case with existing code, how to change animation?

Tags: html, css, image, web, web-deployment

ok, I have don some web development in the past, but am fairly new to "css/webkit" animations.

I have an image on my website, that goes through an animation when a user "hovers" over the image, as so:

[image]

What I want to do is change this animation.

***I want to remove the red "arrows" icon at the bottom-right. I think I want to keep the opacity transition, BUT, I want to display a DIFFERENT image, if the user is hovering over the image.***

Here is the HTML code for the image:

```
<div class="col-md-4">

                            <div class="team" data-animation-name="fadeInRight">

                                <div class="team-photo">
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="demo/team/dfds_seaways_ship.jpg" alt="">
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="gi gi-resize-full"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
```

I did not write this code, and so I am, unfortunately, quite lost.

I think I should show the "css-classes" used here.

```
    /* ==========================================================================
    Team
============================================================================= */
.team {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.team .team-photo {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.team .team-photo figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: opacity 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  opacity: 0;
}
.team .team-photo figcaption a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e35a55;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), background-color 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), background-color 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.team .team-photo figcaption a .fa,
.team .team-photo figcaption a .gi {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.team .team-photo figcaption a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.team:hover .team-photo figcaption,
.team.touch .team-photo figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
.team:hover .team-photo figcaption a,
.team.touch .team-photo figcaption a {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);


.team .team-info {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.team .team-name {
  margin: 0;
}
.team .team-data {
  display: none;
}
```

I tried "just" adding onMouseOver and OnMouseOutEvents, allthough I am unsure if that would be the right/best way to do this, like so:

```
<img src="demo/team/dfds_seaways_ship.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='demo/team/dfds_seaways_ship2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='demo/team/dfds_seaways_ship.jpg'">
```

But it isn't working. This was my naive approach, with my web dev knowledge from a while ago, but I would like to do this by conforming to the CSS approach taken here by the developers of this site.

To be honest, I am lost, so if anyone can help me, or explain to me how I can do this easily with the CSS code that is available, I would be extremely happy, so I can get this done.

If more information is needed, let me know. And I hope the gif above (of the ship) displays fine, on my machine it doesn´t display correctly on IE, but on chrome it displays fine.

Thanks for any and all help!

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would place an image over your image and keep it hidden. Then over hover you make it visible. better imo than adding a javascript event and much more versatil as insteed of "display:none" you may use opacity for a better changing image transition.

I have made a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/auq9dtbh/)** for you so you can see an example.

This is the css's I have added to yours :

```
.other-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
.team:hover .other-image {
    opacity:1;
}
```

and this few lines you may ignore to make the figcaption works as intended (you may have already this anywhere in your project):

```
figure {margin:0; position:relative;}
.team .team-photo {display:inline-block;} 
img {display:block;}
```

To remove the figcaption is at easy as `figcaption {display:none}` or if You want to change the position of the caption then change the value of right and bottom at the `.team .team-photo figcaption a`. If you want an specific change to your figcaption I guess you may explain to us what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your not dealing with an image here but some kind of a icon font can't really tell by the HTML/CSS markup you posted here. If you want to make any changes to the red block in the bottom right you'll have to do some changes to `.team-photo figcaption a` this is the part where you can add styling to the element. If you would like change the content you could do so like this

```
<figcaption>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="gi gi-resize-full">HI</i>
    </a>
</figcaption>
```

You could alternatively use a small icon.

```
<figcaption>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="your-image.jpg">
    </a>
</figcaption>
```

Make sure you'll update the CSS with some new lines if the image is bigger then the element with something like:

```
.team .team-photo figcaption a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Hope this gets you on the way.